# Split an numpy array into two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
A=[(datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 826000), 3.0)
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 827000), nan)
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 832000), nan)
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 833000), nan)
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 3.0)
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 35.0)]
```

And I want to split it into 2 numpy arrays:

```
B=[(datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 826000),
  (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 827000),
  (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 832000),
  (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 833000),
  (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 
  (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000)]

C=[3.0,nan,nan,nan,3.0,35.0]
```

To give you more details this numpy array was at first a dictionnary and I've convert it into a numpy array, you can find the code below:

```
def convertarray(dictionary):
    names=['id','data']
    formats=['datetime64[ms]','f8']
    dtype=dict(names=names, formats=formats)
    result=np.array(dictionary.items(),dtype)
    return result
```

Comment: You have a dtype with fields/fieldnames, or is it really tuples? You should show the array dtype.

Comment: Check out the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @mdurant thank you I found some helpful things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just a have a vanilla array with `dtype=object`, I think your best recourse is to just construct the new arrays by iterating over the old one in a couple list-comprehensions:

import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import datetime

```
A=np.array([(datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 826000), 3.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 827000), nan),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 832000), nan),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 833000), nan),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 3.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 35.0)])

print(A.dtype)

times = np.array([x[0] for x in A])
values = np.array([x[1] for x in A])

print(times)
print(values)
```

With that said, it *might* be slightly cleaner to use a record array:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import datetime

A=np.array([(datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 826000), 3.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 827000), nan),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 832000), nan),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 833000), nan),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 3.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 8, 12, 37, 27, 837000), 35.0)],
   dtype=[('time', object), ('value', float)])

print(A.dtype)

print(A['time'])
print(A['value'])
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea that record arrays even existed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp -- Yep.  I haven't found _too_ many occasions to use them, but I'm sure that others have.  They live predominantly in the [`numpy.recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) namespace.

Comment: @mgilson you've just save my work thank you so much !

Comment: Note that if you find you use record arrays a lot, you may want to consider using pandas.

Comment: @mgilson please one question I tried to put for the time on dtype 'm8[ms]' instead of object but it gave me this error                                   ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta                                   Do you have any idea how can I fix it ?

Comment: @ibia75 -- I'm not super familiar with this part of numpy, but I don't really understand why you're trying to store a `datetime` as a `timedelta` type.  For me, using `'datetime64[ms]'` works instead of using `object` (as you had originally) and it would make sense to me if you wanted to do that ...

Answer (score -1):

You likely want to slice the data. Inserting a `:` for that dimension will select all elements of that dimension.

```
B = A[:, 0]
C = A[:, 1]
```

Comment: This is NOT a multi-dimensional array - it is one-D, but with a compound dtype.